# PostgreSQL view: where condition breaking

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, view, sql-workbench-j

I am working on a project in PostgreSQL. I have a view which joins a couple of tables to have the columns case_id, cohort, status, assignedto, **batch_number**, fail_reason, hold_reason, complete_ts.

On top of this view, I have a query which looks at the batch_number which is a varchar(255) datatype which is created using the year and week number using an UPDATE statement to set batch_number = to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'IYYY-IW') - so when a case is completed it includes the case in the batch number for that week. However I have hit a block where for certain batch numbers the select / where statement does not work. The stats are below:

Case 1: Select * from table_view
Outputs: 40052 records in 3.66 seconds

Case 2: Select * from table_view where Batch_number= ‘2024-09’
Outputs: 2894 records in 3.15 seconds

Case 3: Select * from table_view Batch_number= ‘2024-10’
Outputs: 3765 records in 40.15 seconds.

**Why is the script taking more time for '2024-10'?**
Note that the table_view is not a table or materialised view as this is dynamic and needs to be a view

This has not been an issue for any batch_numbers from 2023-48 until 2024-10 but it is now an issue for week 10 and 11 of 2024. Can someone please help?

Comment: Hi - please update your question with a) the view definition/DDL b) the most detailed EXPLAIN PLANs you can produce for the query in Case 3 and the query for either Case 1 or Case 2

Comment: Without information, nobody knowns. Please share the complete DDL for all tables, indexes and views involved, and the result from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statements. All in plain text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.